# Problems inserting element at the tail of a list JAVA

Tags: java, linked-list, tail, insertion

My assignment is implementing a linkedList as a queue. I'm having a problem adding elements at the tail of the list. I get no Exception but the problem is that when adding a element, the list still is empty afterwards and I really don't see the problem. Someone who has a solution? :)

```
@Override
public void add(E element) {
        if(element == null){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }else{
            this.addNodeLastInQueue(element); 
        }
    
}


public void addNodeLastInQueue(E element){
    
        MyNode<E> nodeToBeAdded = new MyNode<E>(element);  
        if(isEmpty()){
            head = nodeToBeAdded;
            tail = nodeToBeAdded;//Osäker om denna behövs
        }else{
            tail.setNext(nodeToBeAdded);   
            tail = nodeToBeAdded;
        }  
    }
```

I have tried with everything I an come up with

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. What is `head` and `tail`? How are you checking if your list is empty? How is `isEmpty()` defined?

Answer (score 0):

By definition when you add an element in a queue this goes automatically at the end of the list (see FIFO), so you don't need to call the method "addNodeLastInQueue".
The best practice is to call it "enqueue".

Here the method:

```
public void enqueue(E element) {
    Node<E> oldlast = last;
    last = new Node<E>();
    last.e = e; // It refers to the "e" attribute in static class
    last.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) first = last;
    else           oldlast.next = last;
    n++;
}
```

Hint: I suggest you to implement a helper linked list static class in order to provide Node attributes to the queue. In fact i use it in my method.

```
// helper linked list class
private static class Node<E> {
    private E e;
    private Node<E> next;
}
```

I hope I have been of help.
Bye!

Comment: I implemented the node-class as a helpclass - thanks for that hint, much less code now! 

Then I implemented the code you suggested:

public void enQueue(E element) {
        MyNode<E> oldTail = tail;
        tail = new MyNode<E>(element);
        tail.data = element; // It refers to the "e" attribute in static class
        tail.next = null;
        if (isEmpty()) head = tail;
        else           oldTail.next = tail;
    }


But still.... it says that the list is empty

Comment: I needed to add length++; in the end then it worked! Thank you, you have been a big help!

Comment: @Dorra You don't need "add" method: "enqueue" replace it. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyNode<E> {

        private E data;
        private MyNode <E> next;
  
        public MyNode(E data) {
           this.data = data;
           this.next = null; 
        }  
    }

public void enQueue(E element) {
        MyNode<E> oldTail = tail;
        tail = new MyNode<E>(element);
        tail.data = element; 
        tail.next = null;
        if (isEmpty()) head = tail;
        else           oldTail.next = tail;
    }


@Override
public void add(E element) {
    if(element == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }else{
        this.enQueue(element); 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is that the answer to your question?

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.